# Why does my wordpress website act weird on it's own?

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

My [wordpress website](https://www.justcbdstore.com/) is acting weird, padding in the sides - Menu is messed in some pages and works fine in some other pages, I tried disabling all the plugins but the problem remained, all is fine in a minute and the other minute it's all messed up, Not sure where's the problem though i tried everything possible

Comment: It might be the school firewall, but I can't connect to the website. Some simple things to try are clearing your browser's cache and restarting the machine the site is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change the admin credentials. The second thing which you should check the page/post revisions. Because it seems that may be pages are wrongly edited.

Please follow below link for more reference:
[Page Post Revisions](https://en.support.wordpress.com/editors/page-post-revisions/)